# How to paginate custom post type in custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, pagination, custom-post-type

Hi everyone I'm trying to make pagination in custom template page for custom post type. When I click `Older entries` it redirects me to `localhost/videos/page/2/` which is ok but it displays index.php content not videos.php. Here is my videos.php:

```
<?php
/*Template name: Videos*/
get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="row home-row slider-box" id="sliders">

            <?php
               $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                // The Query
                $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_status'=>'publish',
                     'post_type' => 'videos',
                      'orderby' => 'date',
                       'order' => 'DESC',
                        'posts_per_page' => '1',
                         'paged'=>$paged ) );
                $count = 1;
                // The Loop
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                     get_template_part('content', 'videos');
                endwhile;


            next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
?>

</div>
```

And here is how my functions looks:

```
function videos(){
    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'label' => __('Videos'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'videos', 'with_front' => true),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'));
    register_post_type('videos', $args);
    register_taxonomy('videos', 'nagrody');
}
add_action('init', 'videos');
```

Why this pagination doesn't work properly?

Comment: Where do you use `$count = 1;` ?

Comment: It was to count posts I dont use it anymore.

Comment: You sure your routing is ok? When you pass `/videos/` that match exactly with your video page ?

Comment: Yes when I'm on videos page it shows only 1 video and when I clicked to get older posts it displays index.php file.

Comment: When you get **$paged** does it contain something?

Comment: I solved it by myself. You cant have page name videos and same post type. Then pagination doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress pagination works on the main query. So on this page the pagination would work on the `page` not the `WP_Query` you have added since the main query will be to get the videos page.

If you set `has_archive` to true when creating your `videos` post type you can create an archive page for it under `archive-videos.php` and use that to display the posts, and pagination will work.

```
$args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'label' => __('Videos'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'videos', 'with_front' => true),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'));
```

You may be able to fix it without the archive page, try reading here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops

Comment: Good linked post, but in all honesty, I hate nullyfing the main query. It is almost as evil as using `query_posts`, though `query_posts` is still top of the most evil list :-)